# If $\left | z \right | \leq 1$, which of the following must be true?

Tags: absolute-value, gre-exam

If $\left | z \right | \leq 1$, which of the following must be true?

Indicate *all* such statements

A. $z^{2}\leq1$

B. $z^{2}\leq z$

C. $z^{3}\leq z$

Not sure if this is right, but is $\left | z \right | = z^{2}$?

For A), I have $-1\leq z \leq 1$ from $\left | z \right | \leq 1$. But I get $z \leq \pm 1$ from $z^{2}\leq1$.

For B), I get $z \leq 0$ and $z\leq 1$ from $z^{2}\leq z$.

For C), I get $z \leq 0$ and $z \leq \pm 1$ from $z^{3}\leq z$.

I know that the answer is A, but I don't understand why.

Comment: is $z$ a real number?

Comment: @S.C.B. It's a real number.

Comment: (A) It's $z\leq1$ not $z\leq\pm1$.

Comment: (B) $z=-\dfrac12$.

Comment: @MyGlasses Thanks for your input. I am not entirely comfortable working with inequalities, so may I know why?

Comment: If $x$ is a positive number less than $1$, then $0<\cdots<x^4<x^3<x^2<x$. You make it with some number in your mind.

Comment: `is |z|=z^2` No, $|z| = \sqrt{z^2}\,$ for $z \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
&|z|\le 1 \iff-1 \le z \le 1 \\
\\A.& \;(z+1)(z-1)\le 0 &\iff   -1 \le z \le 1
\\B.& \;z(z-1)\le 0 &\iff   0 \le z \le 1
\\C.& \;z(z-1)(z+1)\le 0 &\iff   z\le -1 \text{ or } 0 \le z \le 1
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Statement A. is the only one that is true whenever $|z|\le 1$

Comment: For B, why is $z \geq 0$? Isn't it $z \leq 0$ or $z \leq 1$? Same type of a problem for me to understand C.

Comment: The graph of $f(z)=z(z-1)$ is a parabola with roots at $z=0$ and $z=1$, the graph only dips below the axis between the two roots